# Htaccess global RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables

I'm not sure how to explain this problem so the title is kind of vague!

Well here I go, I'm working on a picture/album page on my website and everything is working great. But I want to add a next/previous picture feature like any good picture website has. I want to passe the different options for sorting out the album by variables.

For now the url on a picture is `http://localhost/photo/174/picture-name/`, I would like to add on this some parameters so that the url then looks like `http://localhost/photo/174/picture-name/album:5/sort:name/`.

With the help of .htaccess I would like to extract the variables `album` and `` sort`.`But the little catch is that I would still want to be able to get to the page with only this url ``http://localhost/photo/174/picture-name/``

For now my .htaccess file looks like this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^photo/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)/$ photo.php?pic_id=$1
```

I tried adding this line in it but it did not work out.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/album:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/sort:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ &album=$2&sort=$3
```

I hope someone has an answer for me,

Have a good day

Joris

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it do?
Try rewriting it to `$1&album=$2&sort=$3` instead of what you have currently. Also if it were me, I would write two separate rules for album and sort because they may not always be together in that order.

Comment: Explain "did not work out". Show complete `.htaccess` file with your rules ordering. Also where are the `album:` and `sort:` literals in your example URL?

Comment: @Ansari with the rule I had I would get a 404 error page saying that the page '&album=5&sort=name' was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^photo/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/[^/]+/album:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/sort:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ photo.php?pic_id=$1&album=$2&sort=$3
```

You also need to change your original rule:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$ photo.php?pic_id=$1
```

Because what you have will match against the URI with the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about this, and your example wasn't correct:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/(.*)/.*/album:(.*)/sort:(.*)/$ photo.php?pic_id=$1&album=$2&sort=$3
```

(for simplicity, I replaced some of the expressions).

Here, http://mydomain.com/photo/174/picture-name/album:5/sort:name/ get rewritten to http://mydomain.com/photo.php?pic_id=174&album=5&sort=name .